# Disable FacebookAds\CrashReporter : Enabled and cURL echo

Tags: php, facebook

I have this event ( working ) :

```
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\Content;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\CustomData;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\DeliveryCategory;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\Event;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\EventRequest;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\Gender;
use FacebookAds\Object\ServerSide\UserData;
```

rest of code and parameters +

```
$request->execute();
```

I get as result

```
FacebookAds\CrashReporter : Enabled

curl \
  -F 'data=[{"event_name":"ViewContent","event_time":1641215668,"user_data":{"client_ip_address":"89.89.89.89"},"custom_data":{"content_ids":["1234"]},"action_source":"website"}]' \
  -F 'test_event_code=TEST73450' \
  -F 'access_token=EAAC8iqoUE98BAAMDjkmFaHspuHkeepZBymLZCjPQT7c98oyRmdfzU2A6CYOxZAFilvXZBVfC9caOTfpDYtW9PqojZBD0TVnsbK7aRt5Uv54TE2fiEhothBRb9oKZCoodIEtdFKXu0G0t6sZBmDedZBZBaNN0cjF9JVxTn3ejnVGMHbcq50NzZAeeUD' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/207387898277294/events
```

How I can disable this eco of result , because the even it self it's tracked.
I need to disable : FacebookAds\CrashReporter : Enabled
and $request->execute(); to give 0 results.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The following is the default code that enables crash reporting to Facebook.

`Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);`

To disable crash reporting, add false to the Api::init function.

`Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token, false);`